# How do you save a snippet of code in SAS Studio as an abbreviation?

Tags: sas, sas-studio

In SAS Studio, is it possible to save a snippet of code, such as a header, as an abbreviation so you can pull-up the code in future programs without having to type the whole thing in again? This can be achieved is SAS EG by selecting "Program > Add Abbreviation Macro", does SAS Studio have a similar option?

Comment: Hmm, no idea.  If you don't get an answer here, try on communities.sas.com in the appropriate community; you might get a dev response there (especially if it's either possible, but hidden, or if it's in development).

Comment: And if it doesn't exist you can add it to the ideas for developers and people can vote on that feature.

Answer (score 2):

The Snippet functionality is available in SAS Studio from version 3.1 on-wards.

Full details are on SAS support site [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/webeditorug/66932/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n002bgjjez3z63n16y88kjsobrha.htm). 
To create your own snippet:

1. Open your .sas file in SAS Studio and select the code that you want to save as a snippet.
2. On the Code tab, click Add to My Snippets button. The Add to My Snippets dialog box appears.
3. Enter a name for the snippet and click Save.

This snippet is now available from the My Snippets folder.